# Calculate the variation of values in amazon redshift database

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to calculate the variation of two values between current month and the previous one.
let's say I have a total calls in different months and and want to have the variation for each month from the previous one.
U have a table contains vendor, month and calls in each month
I have tried the following query nut it gives a wrong results for the same vendor if there is no data in the previous month

```
  select vendor,
         nvl(round(sum(calls),0),0.00) as "total_calls",
         nvl((((lag(CAST(sum(calls) AS decimal) ,0) over(order by month)) -             
               (lag(CAST(sum(calls) AS DECIMAL),1) over(order by month))) / 
               (lag(CAST(sum(calls) AS DECIMAL),1) over(order by month))), 0) as tot_calls_variation
    from table_summary
group by full_month,vendor
order by month,vendor
```

the lag() function returns the row by given index.but this gives wrong results since the variation is calculated by rows and not by each vendor 
wondering if there is any other way to do so ? thanks

Comment: Did you check the option to use WINDOW function on the vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your answers, I have came up with a solution for this, I created a temp table and join it on vendor and month with previous month as following:

```
select vendor,month, 
nvl(round(sum(calls),2),0.0) as "total_calls"
into temp1
from table_summary
group by month,vendor
order by month,vendor
select tb1.month ,tb1.vendor,
((tb1.total_calls - tb2.total_calls) / nullif(tb2.total_calls,0)) as tot_calls_variation
from temp1 tb1
left join temp1 tb2 on (tb1.month -1) = (tb2.month) and tb1.vendor = tb2.vendor 
order by tb1.month ; 
drop table temp1;
```

this is also working when there are no data for calls in some months for vendor

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing your data and desired results, but perhaps you might be better of just going with a self join instead of window functions:

```
SELECT
    month_summary.vendor,
    month_summary.calls,
    month_summary.calls - prev_month_summary.calls / prev_month_summary.calls) as tot_calls_variation
FROM
    (SELECT vendor, full_month, sum(calls) as calls FROM table_summary GROUP BY vendor, full_month) as month_summary
    INNER JOIN (SELECT vendor, full_month, sum(calls) as calls FROM table_summary GROUP BY vendor, full_month) as prev_month_summary ON
        month_summary.vendor = prev_month_summary.vendor AND
        month_summary.full_month - 1 = prev_month_summar.full_month
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with grouping and lag/lead functions is the transition points between groups.

Imagine you have data like this, and you want to group by column A, and perform an operation on the values of C based on the order of column B:

```
A     B     C
===   ===   ===
Y     2015  1
Y     2016  2
Z     2015  3
Z     2016  4
```

When you use the lag function, you're potentially looking at the wrong A column:

```
A     B     C    Lag(A)  Lag(B)  Lag(C)
===   ===   ===  ======  ======  ======
Y     2015  1    null    null    null
Y     2016  2    Y       2015    1
Z     2015  3    Y       2016    2  <-- This is the record causing your problem.
Z     2016  4    Z       2015    3
```

What you generally want to do is including all of the fields you're grouping by and use lag functions on those to make sure you exclude them from your calculations unless the lag function matches the column's value.

I.e., in the above example the reason why the third record is the problem is because A != Lag(A). So if you added `WHERE A = Lag(A)` to your query, it will filter out records like that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Welbog's assessment of the problem: the transition between vendors.

However, I think simplest solution is to use `PARTITION BY vendor` in your `LAG` function. This "closes" the `LAG` window when the value of `vendor` changes.

```
SELECT vendor,full_month,
       NVL(ROUND(SUM(calls),0),0.00) as "total_calls",
       NVL((((LAG(CAST(SUM(calls) AS DECIMAL), 0) OVER(PARTITION BY vendor ORDER BY month)) -             
             (LAG(CAST(SUM(calls) AS DECIMAL), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY vendor ORDER BY month))) / 
             (LAG(CAST(SUM(calls) AS DECIMAL), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY vendor ORDER BY month)))
           , 0) as tot_calls_variation
    FROM table_summary
GROUP BY vendor,full_month
ORDER BY month,vendor
```

One further thing, you did not mention whether `table_summary` contains zeroes for months where the vendors have no calls. If it does **not** then `LAG` will produce incorrect results.